# jsHint identifying ?. operator as an error

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, lint, jshint, grunt-contrib-jshint

Has any one had success getting the new ?. operator in Javascript to pass jsHint? I have my project set up with esversion: 6 already, but I still get multiple errors. It appears that jsHint thinks it is an incorrect ternary operator. I'm aware I can have jsHint ignore the line, but I would prefer if I didn't have to do that each time I use the operator.

Comment: JSHint is positively ancient – you should probably look at ESLint instead.

Comment: It's not an ES6 feature - optional chaining is in the latest ES11 standard.

Comment: @AKX I agree, but it's not my call to make.

Comment: @VLAZ That would explain it. Thanks.

Comment: What's your node version? Please update to 14.x and try.

Comment: I'm on the newest version. I'm using this inside a grunt build process, so I don't think that's what is impacting it.

Comment: @VLAZ or ES2020 as ECMA calls it ;)